# 2 columns variable heights, longest always scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, sidebar

The problem:
Typical site layout, main column with content, sidebar with extras.
On some pages the main content is longer than the sidebar, on others the sidebar is longer.

Both sides scroll down to the bottom of the shortest column, then the longest continues to scroll as the other stays in view.

I recently found two different solutions to this as jQuery plugins but after two hours of searching I cannot find them again!

This is a terrible question for stackoverflow, and I apologise, but does anyone know what I'm talking about and what the plugins are called..?

Comment: [Sticky Scroll?](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)

Comment: THANK YOU DAN!!!! Wow, I was pulling my hair out, that's exactly what I was looking for. Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

[Sticky Scroll](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)